# Checking to see if a bash script is running in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: bash, shell, bitbucket-pipelines

Is there a way to check if a script is running inside a bitbucket pipeline. I want to do something along these lines.

```
if $running_in_pipelines
    do_something
fi
```

I have looked along checking whether the script is running in a docker container but I don't want to use that since the script can be run inside a docker container running other than a pipeline as well.

Comment: Have a look as [Variables in pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/variables-in-pipelines-794502608.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @user7369820's comment, this simple check works

```
if [ -z "$CI" ]; then
    echo "Not running in pipelines"
fi
```

The assumption here is that nobody defines `CI` to be an environment variable in your host system.

Comment: According to this local pipeline runner tool on [Github](https://github.com/ktomk/pipelines/#environment), there are some other (more verbose) environment variables which might be easier to inspect