# Detect if selenium test run in Bitbucket Pipeline

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, bitbucket-pipelines, xvfb

I want to know if it's possible to do something like this :

```
if( "#in bitbucket pipeline" ):

        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        cls.selenium = WebDriver(options=options)

else:
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()
```

Simply because i need to run my test in headless on bitbucket but not localy..

**Python 3.6**

**django 3**

Comment: See a proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54142217/7446465)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get over it whit a method that check if the test is running in a docker container